# apns_client which usese openssl fails on eventlet.monkey_patch()

Tags: python, openssl, eventlet

So I am able to send messages using apns_client ( more so lately using apns_clerk because of the ssl error)

But now i need to use eventlet to make is nonblocking.

so i was suggested to go and monkeypatch all the libraries in the very beginning.

so i do

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

the problem is now i get this error and am not able to send messages:-

' WARNING:apns_clerk.backends.stdio:Failed to establish socket/SSL connection to     ('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apns_clerk/backends/stdio.py", line 168, in _open_connection
    self._connect_and_handshake()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apns_clerk/backends/stdio.py", line 205, in _connect_and_handshake
    self._connection.do_handshake()
WantReadError'

https://bitbucket.org/sardarnl/apns-client/overview

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information to debug your problem:

`python -V
python -c 'import eventlet; print(eventlet.__version__)'`

URL to which you are trying to connect or minimal code to reproduce it.

Try to update to latest eventlet v0.16, there was a bug fix related to Python 2.7.9.

You may want to open an issue here https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/new

Comment: will update and try thanks ... I did open an issue here https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

I use Python3.4.3 and eventlet 0.17.4 and have the same problem.

Seems that we should use eventlet's version of OpenSSL. Here is my (very dirty) workaround, for now couldn't figure out anything better:

- in eventlet/green/OpenSSL/**init**.py fix imports to be compatible with python3 (`import rand` -> `from . import rand`)
- In apns_clerk/backends/stdio.py replace `import OpenSSL` with `from eventlet.green import OpenSSL`.

This worked for me. (Another issue is it hangs if there is only one valid device, I worked it around by adding «dummy» invalid device.)

I believe there is a better way to make `apns_clerk` use greenified OpenSSL, but I couldn't (yet) figure it out becuase `eventlet` documentation is very silent about it.